# Get the last three statuses and posts on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying get the last three posts and statuses, as I know the status table contains only the status that I put on my Facebook page. The posts table contains a shared link, posts made by me or other users, so I want to: compare the last three statuses with the last three posts and take only the most 3 new (created date) from them, so I need to make check the created date or updated date for both sides and the output should be three.

**I have tried:**

Take the last three posts and the last three statuses, compare the updated date with the most updated three, put them in an array. That took a lot of [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code. Can I do that with [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last three posts and statuses via [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). Use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id?fields=id,name,statuses.limit(3).fields(message),posts.fields(message,caption,description)
```

For more help, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

#### FQL

For getting statuses

```
SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid=fb_id
```

For getting posts

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

But for all these you should have the permissions for accessing them. See
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id?fields=id,name,statuses.fields(message).limit(3),posts.fields(message,caption,description).limit(3) , you forget add limit(3) for both side , ok thats nice , now i need to pick only the most new 3 from these six ouput .

Comment: i mean now i have 6 object (3 from posts , 3 from status) i need pick from these 6 only 3 (the most 3 new) object

Comment: @moata_u hi for getting the last three statuses you can use the limit propert ie fbid?fields=id,name,statuses.limit(3).fields(message)

Comment: yea i know , problem is : after getting last 3 post and last 3 status , i want pick only the 3 last object from these 6 object (posts and status) ..

Comment: Oh.You can store these 6 objects in an array then read them either by the order of date or sort them in the order of date.

Comment: that what am doing just am thinking if there is a way that i can do with either grapg api or fql